# Prove by Double Counting Method $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^m \binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{r + k} = \binom{m + n}{m + r}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, permutations, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

Show by combinatorial arguments that:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^m \binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{r + k} = \binom{m + n}{m + r}$$

Hello ,  I want to prove this argument by double counting method, i kinda have an idea of proving by comb args. but not by double counting...
Can someone give any clues or ideas? thanks :)

Comment: It might help to first look at $\binom{m}{k}$ instead as $\binom{m}{m-k}$.  Now... Suppose that you have $m$ men and $n$ women.  In how many ways can you form a committee of size _____?  By picking simultaneously?  By picking genders separately?

Comment: You can write directly your question by using $\LaTeX$ or/and $\texttt{MathJax}$. For instance,
$\$\texttt{\sum_{k = 0}^{m}{m \choose k}{n \choose r + k} = {m + n \choose m + r}}\$$ yields $\sum_{k = 0}^{m}{m \choose k}{n \choose r + k} = {m + n \choose m + r}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin That's interesting, I've never seen the syntax for `\choose` done correctly and have been in the habit of using `\binom{ }{ }` instead.  (*I've seen too many people use it incorrectly though, I guess its more noticeable when its wrong than when its right*)  Regardless, @ Johnathan, a link for resources on typing with MathJax can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @JMoravitz $\texttt{binom}$ is fine too !!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially Vandermonde's identity. Consider $m$ men and $n$ women. In how many ways may we pick a committee of $m+r$ members?

On the one hand, this is just $\binom{m+n}{m+r}$.

On the other hand, if we pick $m-k$ men, then we need to pick $r+k$ women. Hence we have $$\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{r+k}=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{m-k}\binom{n}{r+k}=\binom{m+n}{m+r}.$$

Comment: oh thanks , i get it now,this really helped :)